# React Native - npm start doesn't start

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-start, watchman

I'm trying to work with React Native in Fedora 26, and I have followed the [facebook tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.21/docs/getting-started-on-linux.html) until then.

Everything was going very well, until I try to start the application
with npm

> npm start

And receive this error:

```
> cardbook@0.1.0 start $HOME/cardbook
> react-native-scripts start

9:31:54 AM: Starting packager...
***ERROR STARTING PACKAGER***
Starting React Native packager...
Scanning 770 folders for symlinks in $HOME/cardbook/node_modules (19ms)
Loading dependency graph.
Running packager on port 19001.


jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
  Error: Watchman error: A non-recoverable condition has triggered.  Watchman needs your help!
The triggering condition was at timestamp=1507206724: inotify-add-watch($HOME/cardbook/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/lib/build/tmp/expandedArchives/classes.jar_6745ow7srqaaq6vs8k7dkn33k/com/google/android/gms/common/data) -> The user limit on the total number of inotify watches was reached; increase the fs.inotify.max_user_watches sysctl
All requests will continue to fail with this message until you resolve
the underlying problem.  You will find more information on fixing this at
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify-add-watch. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.
```

Additional Information:

- watchman version: 4.9.0
- npm version: 3.10.10

Could any pure and kind-hearted soul help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running my application right now on my phone. I followed an heuristic approach, trying to resolve the problem quickly, then there is a great lack of information. Anyway I solved it like that:

First I uninstalled watchman:

```
$ sudo make uninstall
```

So with yarn (note that I didn't use npm, which still doesn't work), I received the following tips:

```
yarn start
yarn run v1.1.0
$ react-native-scripts start
11:15:08 AM: Unable to start server
  See https://git.io/v5vcn for more information, either install watchman or run the following snippet:
    sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024
    sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=12288
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Obviously I followed the instructions:

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=12288
```

And received my QR-code with succes.

Answer (score 0):

Just type following commands to fix it if you don't wanna install Watchman

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_instances=1024
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=12288
```

Comment: Thanks! But I already was doing that. It was the final part of my answer :)